# Getting Visual Studio to display the C# code that's causing an error

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I am debugging a button in my C# code, and I get a JavaScript runtime error thrown on click from a script that I have never touched at a `throwerror()` line. My coworker, on the other hand, gets an error that points to the actual line in the C# code that is causing the problem. We can't seem to figure out how to get my copy of Visual Studio to throw the helpful non-JS errors.

When I debug (Clicking 'Start Debugging' with Internet Explorer selected), and I try to debug a asp.net button, I receive an error in ScriptResource.axd, like this:

[image]

And is shows me that the error is here:

[image]

Now, when my colleague does the same process to debug the same code, this is the error he receives:

[image]

We are both using IE to debug in Visual Studio. Both VS instances are 2012. I have not come across this issue and neither has my colleague. Does anyone have any insight to this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, but it's not the specific c# error that I am asking for help with. What I am trying to figure out is why Visual studio might throw my co-worker an error pointing to the issue in the code, but throw me a generic JS error. Sorry If I did not make that obvious enough

Comment: I tried to edit your title to reflect that, but it's a little ham-handed since I'm not familiar with Visual Studio at all. You should edit too, to add any details you can think of and make it more clear that you're asking for debug _process_ help rather than for someone to fix code they can't see.

Comment: Do you have a debugger attached to the backend? Just viewing the web page will not do this.

Comment: Visual Studio will display JS errors only if you're using IE.

Comment: I have made an edit to my post since I have been misunderstood. I know the differences between client side language and server side language. This is why I'm confused why I'm getting a client side error message when I'm trying to debug a server side asp.net control with no JS.

Comment: Perhaps it's IE options? Is script debugging turned on for you? (Internet Options, Advanced, Browsing, Disable script debugging)

Comment: We've tried this, unfortunately did not work

Comment: These appear to be 2 separate, unrelated exceptions. One is a javascript client side exception, and the other is a server side exception. It could be that you have code on the server side that handles the exception and returns the exception to the javascript?  In this case you might need to turn on "break on all exceptions" in Visual Studio (which your teammate may have turned on).

Comment: Try going into Visual Studio, Debug menu > Exceptions.  Then check the "Thrown" checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  This will cause Visual Studio to break on all exceptions that are thrown, even if they are handled via some error handling logic.  Then see if the server side exception that your colleague is seeing will show up for you.  Also make sure you both have the same version of source code, same IE versions, and same Visual Studio service pack versions installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried comparing Exceptions settings in "DEBUG->Exceptions..." with your coworker
[image]

Comment: I ended up having to go to Debug -> Options and settings, General -> And check 'Enable Just My Code' in order to see the 'User-Unhandled' column in DEBUG-Exceptions. Once I unchecked JavaScript Runtime Exceptions, my issue was solved! What is really strange though is that my coworker actually does have JavaScript Runtime Exeptions checked, but now that I don't, we receive the same error. Regardless, thank you for helping me get to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptResource.axd` actually does create runtime generated JavaScript.
Have you tried using the continue button? It might cause the follow up error to appear.

Comment: Tried this, does not work either. Just uninstalled and re-installed VS as well and it did not fix the issue. Do you think it could be a problem with the project itself?